# Does KEY_WOW64_64KEY have any effect on 32 bit Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, 64-bit, registry, 32-bit

It *appears* that specifying the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28VS.85%29.aspx)) when accessing a registry key under 32-bit Windows XP has no effect - that is, no error is thrown, and the key is opened as if you hadn't had the flag set.

I know Windows 2000 throws an error when it encounters this flag.

I want to make sure my app is compatible with as many versions of windows (2k and later) as possible.

Is there a Microsoft reference that specifies each version of Windows' behaviour for this flag? In particular, I'd like something that validates my assumption that it has no effect at all on post-2k 32-bit Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this Windows page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-key-security-and-access-rights?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Both

```
KEY_WOW64_32KEY (0x0200)

KEY_WOW64_64KEY (0x0100)
```

will be ignored on 32-bit Windows.

And those flags are not supported on Windows 2000.

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak to Windows 2000 or XP, but I know that on Vista and above, KEY_WOW64_64KEY opens the registry key in the 64bit registry if it's a 64bit OS and the 32bit registry if it's a 32bit OS.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested on Windows XP 32 bit, and it seems to work OK.

Answer (score -1):

Also, you should usually be avoiding this key - WOW64 provides a pretty complete "illusion" to 32-bit apps; just write your app properly on 32-bit without this flag, and it will still work on WOW64. Don't try to use this flag (and other mechanisms) to be "64-bit compatible".

Comment: I need to detect whether certain other applications are installed, and where - and they have 64-bit versions.

Comment: In that case, you should probably write your app as 64-bit, then inspect the Wow6432Node if needed, instead of forcing yourself to think for every file/reg/path access, "Should I care about redirection?"

Comment: Agreed, but converting and recompiling a large Delphi7 codebase to 64bit is not really an option right now :P