# Risks of using KEY_WOW64_64KEY on a 32bit application

Tags: winapi

We currently have a 32bit application that requires various key/value pairs to be loaded from the registry before use.

Previously we had completed this by loading the .reg as part of the installation. Running it on 64-bit Windows the .reg components end up in the 64-bit store, but our 32-bit application looks in the 32-bit store.

I was thinking of using [KEY_WOW64_64KEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724878%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to force our 32-bit application to always use the 64-bit store however [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633673/does-key-wow64-64key-have-any-effect-on-32-bit-windows/1637884#1637884) advises against that. Then I thought we could change the .reg file to point to the 32-bit store but the [comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252297/why-is-regopenkeyex-returning-error-code-2-on-vista-64bit/291067#291067) advises against assuming the key will always be called "Wow6432Node"

Is there any perferred way to do this (other than migrating the whole app to 64-bit)? What are risks of a 32-bit application using the 64-bit store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't pass the HKEY handle to non Reg* functions that expect x86==native registry I don't think there are any risks. (Filesystem redirection on the other hand is not per handle and can cause problems if a sub-function calls LoadLibrary or CoCreateInstance etc)

If using KEY_WOW64_64KEY seems like too much of a hack, why not have the (32 bit) installer write to the registry instead of using .reg files? The only downside by doing this is that if you create a x64 version of your app in the future it will not share the settings with the x86 version. (This might be a good thing or a bad thing)

Comment: +1 don't use .reg files, get the installer to do the work is def the way to go